# Enable/Disable jquery toggle and asp panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on creating a control that will enable/disable a section of an aspx page when clicking a button. I found a code snippet in jquery that will do this for all values but I want to restrict the lock/edit portion to an asp Panel.

1) Is this possible?

2) How do I change the jquery code to only toggle the fields within Panel1?

I am very new to Jquery.

Thank you for any and all future guidance!

```cs
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChangeControl3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test_ChangeControl3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Lock/Edit Control</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet"href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnEnableDisable").toggle(function() {

    $("*").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
     $(this).attr("disabled", ""); 
    }, function() {
     $("*").attr("disabled", ""); 

     });
   });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<div>
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFname" Text="First Name:" ></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fname"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLname" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lname"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCompany" Text="Company:" ></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cname"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</asp:Panel>  
  <br />
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnEnableDisable" Text="Lock/Edit" />
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="qrentown" value="Do you own a home?" /> Do you own a home?<br /><br/>
   <select name="rentown">
   <option value="own">Own</option>
   <option value="rent">Rent</option>
   <option value="none">N/A</option>
  </select><br/>
  <input readonly="readonly" value="Describe your living situation"/><br />
  <textarea rows="3" cols="40" > </textarea>
  <br/><br/>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the panel id Panel1 in your jQuery:

```
$("[id$='Panel1']").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Note, this gets an id that ends in your id as the server will add to the start of that id.

Same issue with `btnEnableDisable`

Toggle is an animation event, you want a click event.

SO, let's use your button to hold the current state of things and then enable/disable based on your click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$='btnEnableDisable']").data('isenabled', true);//enabled assumption
    $("[id$='btnEnableDisable']").click(function() {
        var currentState = $(this).data('isenabled');
        if (currentState) {
            $("[id$='Panel1']").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $("[id$='Panel1']").children().removeProp("disabled");
        }
        $(this).data('isenabled', !currentState);
    });
});
```

pretty verbose to show exactly what we are doing here :)

Answer (score 0):

I noramlly show and hide panels just using a surrounding div tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    hideAllDivs = function () {
        $("#div_id").hide();

    };

   $("#btnEnableDisable").click(function() {

        $("#div_id").show();

    };
</script
```

the div content looks like this

```
<div id="div_id">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFname" Text="First Name:" ></asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fname"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLname" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lname"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCompany" Text="Company:" ></asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cname"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>



<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnEnableDisable" Text="Lock/Edit" />
```

Hope this helps,